# Random codec information in the middle of an mp4 file

Tags: c, file, mp4, h.264, file-format

I am trying to get the NAL units from an mp4 file using C. I got inside the "mdat" atom and tried extracting the NAL units. The first 3 were as "size, data" where size is the size of data in bytes. After that, I continued looking for the next unit. The size was 0xde02004c, which is too big. When I checked it with the hex editor, I saw that that is indeed true. But then I noticed the "Lavc" written right next to it.

```
00004930  92 43 19 61 93 4e de 02  00 4c 61 76 63 35 38 2e  |.C.a.N...Lavc58.|
00004940  35 34 2e 31 30 30 00 42  20 08 c1 18 38 00 00 00  |54.100.B ...8...|
00004950  c9 01 9e 41 79 09 7f 7a  03 ed 3f 54 39 fb c2 01  |...Ay..z..?T9...|
00004960  c4 53 76 51 2d bf 57 5f  04 25 00 b9 fb df 43 67  |.SvQ-.W_.%....Cg|
00004970  f3 27 b9 f5 d7 e7 95 e9  b4 06 14 6b 4a c7 4e ff  |.'.........kJ.N.|
00004980  23 ed 8f 17 d0 4d d4 21  a7 b3 84 0e 65 60 41 67  |#....M.!....e`Ag|
00004990  ec db 10 c9 b3 4c 3f 71  df 6b 73 c2 df cd fe 85  |.....L?q.ks.....|
```

The previous NAL unit ends right before the bytes "de 02 00 4c", so that should be the size of the next one. But it isn't. It looks like codec information. Why?

Edit: The first bytes of the first nalu:

```
00 00 02 af 06 05 ff ff ┊ ab dc 45 e9 bd e6 d9 48 │00•×••××┊××E××××H│
b7 96 2c d8 20 d9 23 ee ┊ ef 78 32 36 34 20 2d 20 │××,× ×#×┊×x264 - │
```

the second:

```
00 00 41 80 65 ┊ 88 84 01 ff 5e e7 6f ea
36 23 b7 5d 16 f8 5f 54 ┊ a3 5d 7c 9e ac d1 9b f6
```

and the third:

````
00 04 cb 41 9a 22 6c 5f
6e 75 69 b0 e3 e1 d9 c9 ┊ d4 71 cb 05 a3 60 09 71 ```
````

Comment: **(1)** Can you [show us](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65952243/edit) the first 16 bytes of each of those previous three Nalu's? **(2)** Why aren't you using the Moov atom to double-check the expected sizes and offsets of samples (frames)?

Comment: @VC.One I added them now

Comment: mdat boxes are not supposed to contain continuously placed NAL units; they are blobs hosting parts referenced from other boxes. you should reconsider the way you are processing mp4 files in first place, taking into account their true structure.